# Flutter - BLoC Testing BlocListener + Navigation

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-test, flutter-bloc

I want to test something like

```
When user taps a button -> It triggers a BlocListener (new state) -> Navigate to New Screen
```

Currently i've something like:

```dart
BlocListener<UserBloc, UserState>(
  listener: (_, state) {
    Navigator.pushNamed('login');
  }
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

await tester.pumpWidget(BlocProvider(
  create: (_) => userBlocMock,
  child: MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen()),
));

await tester.enterText(find.byKey('my-key1'), 'johndoe@example.com');
await tester.enterText(find.byKey('my-key2'), 'password');
await tester.tap(find.byType(LogOutButton), findsOneWidget));

await tester.pump();

expect(find.byType(LogInScreen), findsOneWidget);
```

It always fail, can you provide me an example of how to make this work please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by using `await tester.pumpAndSettle()` rather than just `await tester.pump()`. More information can be found in the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html